# Magento Media Gallery Uploader in custom module

Tags: magento

I want to add Media Gallery Uploader in my custom module (like the product images uploader). I have searched a lot but could not get appropriate information regarding it. I found https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21161/using-the-magento-image-uploader-in-custom-module and tried a lot but could not get success.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom module also for uploading multiple images.

You will need to call first a custom javascript file, you will need to upload this file to your skin folder:

Use this js code:

```
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
 $('#add_more').click(function() {
 $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
 $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),
 $("<br/><br/>")
 ));
 });

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
 if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

 var z = abc - 1;
 var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
 $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
 reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

 $(this).hide();
 $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'img', src: 'http://yoursite.com/skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/images/ico-delete.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
 }));
 }
 });

//To preview image
 function imageIsLoaded(e) {
 $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
 };

 $('#upload').click(function(e) {
 var name = $(":file").val();
 if (!name)
 {
 alert("Debe subir una imagen en el primer cuadro");
 e.preventDefault();
 }
 });
});
```

Then add your form in your theme:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('yourmodule/yourindexaction'); ?>" method="post">
<p>Only JPEG,PNG,JPG.</p> 
 <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>
 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
 <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add more images"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" id="upload" style="cursor: pointer;" class="upload"/>
 </form>
```

Please note on the form action im calling the action method of the custom module, on that action you will get the post fields and process the fields.

and then to loop all the images please do this in the action on the module:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array
```

Please refer this site for more info: http://www.formget.com/upload-multiple-images-using-php-and-jquery/

I hope this helps and let me know any issues...